# How to join between the two other tables in current controller in cakephp3?

Tags: php, cakephp, join

I want to join between the two other tables in current controller and insert result in current controller table. This is my code but does'nt work:

```
class UesrsController extends AppController {

    public function addRoom() {
         $rooms = TableRegistry::get("Rooms");
         $row = $rooms
             ->find('list', array('fields' => 'id'))
             ->join([
                 'table' => 'dormitories', 
                 'conditions' => ['dormitories.id=rooms.dormitory_id']
             ])
             ->where(['dormitories.name =' => 'aaa'])
         ;
         $this->set('row', $row);
         return $rooms;
    }
}
```

In above code, I want to join between dormitories and rooms and save result to users table.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

And I think you need to add a type of join. But I can be wrong on that one.

```
class UesrsController extends AppController {

public function addRoom() {
     $rooms = TableRegistry::get("Rooms");
     $rooms
         ->find('list', array('fields' => 'id'))
         ->join([
             'table' => 'dormitories', 
             'type' => 'LEFT',
             'conditions' => ['dormitories.id=rooms.dormitory_id',
                  'dormitories.name =' => 'aaa'
              ]
         ])
     ;
}
}
```